# Overleaf | Image compilation differences between the built-in and downloaded pdf

Tags: graphics, overleaf, output

After writing a document in overleaf, I see the following output in the built-in pdf viewer-

[image]

**Note the differences between figure in the two outputs.**

But after downloading the pdf, when i open it in a pdf reader (Adobe Acrobat Reader), I see the following output.

[image]

I am new to writing in LaTeX and am using Overleaf. How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you check with a different Viewer (Sumatra PDF for example) if the lines are there. Barely visible lines that disappear at certain levels of magnification are usually a viewer issue, but the question here is whether the lines are really there in your document or not. If they are really there you should probably contact Overleaf about this and ask them to investigate whether their viewer should show the lines. ...

Comment: ... If you want help to remove those lines, we need to know how you embed the images and *probably* also need access to the images you embed to help. (It would be great if you could try and reproduce this issue in a small example document with as little code as possible.)